# Vector space with algebraic independent numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a $\mathbb{R} \cap \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ (the set of all algebraic numbers)-vector space which base is $(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n)$ where all the $(a_i)$ are all algebraically independent with the others and are algebraically independent with $0$.

Then we have $\dim \mathcal{E} = n$ and the elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are defined by : $$\forall u \in \mathcal{E}, u = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i q_i$$Where $\forall i, q_i \in \mathbb{R} \cap\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

I have found that $\mathcal{E}_{+\infty} \not\simeq \mathbb{R}$ (there is no isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space and $\mathcal{E}$ even of infinite dimension). This is apparently because $\mathbb{R} \cap\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ is countable and obviously not $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is then : if we allow $\mathcal{E}$ to be """$\aleph_1$-dimensional""" (yes, I'm well aware that it's absurd to use such a notation, especially because $\aleph_1$ is an ordinal and not a quantity, hence the presence of inverted commas, and I'm sorry but I can't find a better way to express this idea) , so with a continuous base not defined by a sequence but by a bijective application $\omega : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \cap\bar{\mathbb{Q}})$ (the base of $\mathcal{E}$ is then $\left\{ \omega(x) \mid x\in\mathbb{R} \right\}$ if I may say so), can we have $\mathcal{E}_{\aleph_1} \simeq \mathbb{R}$ ?

In other words, can we express $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{R} \cap\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-vector space ?

Comment: *independ**e**nt* has no *a*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, sorry, I will correct this !

Comment: You write about a set that is algebraically independent with zero, but no set is algebraically independent with zero.

Comment: Anyway, the reals are certainly a vector space over the real algebraics, as they satisfy all the vector space axioms. Maybe you are asking whether we can find an explicit basis for this vector space?

Comment: I'm not convinced that we've succeeded in answering your question, Kappa, but maybe keeping in mind the advice you're been given you can rephrase it to make clear just what the difficulty is?

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap \mathbb{R}$ be the field of **real** algebraic numbers. Then clearly $F \subset \mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{R}/F$ is a field extension and, therefore, a vector space.

The dimension of this vector space is $2^{\aleph_0}$, which isn’t $\aleph_1$ unless you assume CH.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}$ is not a vector space over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ in any natural way, since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ contains complex numbers.

Comment: Yes, my bad ! I somehow forgot that $\bar{\mathbb{Q}} \neq \mathbb{R} \cap \bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, I will correct this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: So the base of the vector space is the set of all transcendental numbers ?

Comment: @N. auf Kappa : edit, the set of all transcendental real numbers

Comment: No. Some sets of transcendental numbers, like $e$ and $2e$ and $\sqrt{2}e$, are linearly dependent. There is no way to explicitly describe a basis for this vector space.

Comment: oh yes ! So the base is $\mathbb{R}\setminus(\mathbb{R}\cap\bar{\mathbb{Q}})/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation "linearly dependent" ?

Comment: No. “Linearly dependent” is not an equivalence relation, because three elements can be linearly dependent even if no two of them are. It’s not a relation on pairs of elements.